# SharePoint list not reflecting data entered in PowerApps form

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms

I created a SharePoint list a few months ago where users enter their findings in certain columns in correlation with an ID number. I made an update in the last month in the PowerApps form to convert certain fields to dropdown. For example, now if they select a Username from the dropdown list, the other two fields automatically populate corresponding data from a separate, 2nd sharepoint list. Ex. If you selected D1872 from the dropdown list, the Department would populate as "Call Center". I noticed the data not reflecting correctly recently and when I opened a row record in edit view and scanned form, it re-updated the corrected information that was actually entered by the user. I then would have to save it in order for it to reflect correctly in SharePoint. How do I get the entire sharepoint list updated without doing this one by one in the list?